# Firefox sync: Is it two way?

Tags: firefox

So I have two laptops - both of which I regularly use. I have important bookmarks, history, etc. in Firefox of both laptops.

I have signed-in into Firefox in one of the laptops, but not in the other.

Now I have to give up one of the laptops (the one where I have signed-in).

How do I make sure that I can retain history and bookmarks of both laptops?

I am thinking of signing in into the other laptop, but a bit afraid that Firefox may obliterate the existing history and bookmarks, and replace it with the one associated with the account. Is it true?

Answer (score 3):

> Sync lets you share your data and preferences (such as your bookmarks,
>   history, passwords, open tabs, Reading List and installed add-ons)
>   across all your devices.

[Sync](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-sync-my-computer) is designed to **share** between your devices, not delete and/or replace.

So, when you sign in with the new laptop, it will share all the items with your other devices and vice versa.

If you don't trust it, then make a backup copy of your settings before adding the device to your synced devices.